# how to see content of a method pointer?

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, reinterpret-cast

```
typedef int (D::*fptr)(void);
fptr bfunc;
bfunc=&D::Bfunc;
cout<<(reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long>(bfunc)&0xffffffff00000000)<<endl;
```

complete code available at : https://ideone.com/wRVyTu

I am trying to use `reinterpret_cast`, but the compiler throws error

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()': prog.cpp:49:51: error: invalid cast from type 'fptr {aka int (D::*)()}' to type 'long long unsigned int'   cout<<(reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long>(bfunc)&0xffffffff00000000)<<endl;
```

My questions are :

1. why is `reinterpret_cast` not suitable for this occasion?
2. Is there another way, I can see the contents of the method pointer?

Comment: Pointers to member functions are "implementation defined", and often more complex than a single value.

Comment: A method pointer isn't necessarily an address, nor is it necessarily representable as an integer.

Comment: @MatsPetersson @molbdnilo
The size of method pointer as seen by `sizeof` is same as `long long` in my case, so there should be some way to look into the bit pattern of the thing(for lack of better word) that `sizeof` considers as method pointer.

Comment: But sizeof(struct {int, int}) would also [in a 64-bit archiecture] be same as a 64-bit long long...

Comment: I think you run into aliasing problems in the simple ways of casting to other than `char`.  So you could cast `&bfunc` as `char*` and easily inspect from there.  Or there are some ways to use a union.  (The `reinterpret_cast` to do what you originally tried would be `reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long&>` but I think that has aliasing problems).

Comment: What do you actually expect to see?

Comment: @MatsPetersson yes, you are right. I just wanted to see the internals of method pointer. How offset and address is stored. Another unrelated question. why `reinterpret_cast<long long>(struct{int,int})` doesn't work? Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect `reinterpret_cast<long long>(struct{int,int})` to actually do? You have two, probably independent values in integers, and you just want the compiler to randomly convert that to a long long in whatever byte-order the bytes of the two `int`s are stored? It doesn't really make a huge amount of sense - `union` allows you to tell the compiler to store bytes of one type "on top of" other bytes, but it's really not a good idea to do that.

Comment: @MatsPetersson `and you just want the compiler to randomly convert that to a long long in whatever byte-order the bytes of the two ints are stored?` yeah, actually that was the idea. It will not have any real use, but it can be used to inspect say, in which order the members of `struct` are stored. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using clang++ to compile a slightly modified version of your code (removed all the `cout` to not get thousands of lines...), we get this for `main`:

```
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %bfunc = alloca { i64, i64 }, align 8
  %dfunc = alloca { i64, i64 }, align 8
  store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
  store { i64, i64 } { i64 1, i64 16 }, { i64, i64 }* %bfunc, align 8
  store { i64, i64 } { i64 9, i64 0 }, { i64, i64 }* %dfunc, align 8
  ret i32 0
}
```

Note that the `bfunc` and `dfunc` are two 64-bit integer values. If I compile for 32-bit x86 it is two `i32` (so 32-bit integer values).

So, if we make `main` look like this:

```
int main() {
    // your code goes here

    typedef int (D::*fptr)(void);

    fptr bfunc;
    fptr dfunc;

    bfunc=&D::Bfunc;
    dfunc=&D::Dfunc;

    D d;
    (d.*bfunc)();

    return 0;
}
```

the generated code looks like this:

```
; Function Attrs: norecurse uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %bfunc = alloca { i64, i64 }, align 8
  %dfunc = alloca { i64, i64 }, align 8
  %d = alloca %class.D, align 8
  store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
  store { i64, i64 } { i64 1, i64 16 }, { i64, i64 }* %bfunc, align 8
  store { i64, i64 } { i64 9, i64 0 }, { i64, i64 }* %dfunc, align 8
  call void @_ZN1DC2Ev(%class.D* %d) #3
  %0 = load { i64, i64 }, { i64, i64 }* %bfunc, align 8
  %memptr.adj = extractvalue { i64, i64 } %0, 1
  %1 = bitcast %class.D* %d to i8*
  %2 = getelementptr inbounds i8, i8* %1, i64 %memptr.adj
  %this.adjusted = bitcast i8* %2 to %class.D*
  %memptr.ptr = extractvalue { i64, i64 } %0, 0
  %3 = and i64 %memptr.ptr, 1
  %memptr.isvirtual = icmp ne i64 %3, 0
  br i1 %memptr.isvirtual, label %memptr.virtual, label %memptr.nonvirtual

memptr.virtual:                                   ; preds = %entry
  %4 = bitcast %class.D* %this.adjusted to i8**
  %vtable = load i8*, i8** %4, align 8
  %5 = sub i64 %memptr.ptr, 1
  %6 = getelementptr i8, i8* %vtable, i64 %5
  %7 = bitcast i8* %6 to i32 (%class.D*)**
  %memptr.virtualfn = load i32 (%class.D*)*, i32 (%class.D*)** %7, align 8
  br label %memptr.end

memptr.nonvirtual:                                ; preds = %entry
  %memptr.nonvirtualfn = inttoptr i64 %memptr.ptr to i32 (%class.D*)*
  br label %memptr.end

memptr.end:                                       ; preds = %memptr.nonvirtual, %memptr.virtual
  %8 = phi i32 (%class.D*)* [ %memptr.virtualfn, %memptr.virtual ], [ %memptr.nonvirtualfn, %memptr.nonvirtual ]
  %call = call i32 %8(%class.D* %this.adjusted)
  ret i32 0
}
```

This is not entirely trivial to follow, but in essense:

```
  %memptr.adj = Read adjustment from bfunc[1]
  %2 = %d[%memptr.adj]
  cast %2 to D*
  %memptr.ptr = bfunc[0]
  if (%memptr.ptr & 1) goto is_virtual else goto is_non_virtual

is_virtual:
  %memptr.virtual=vtable[%memptr.ptr-1]
  goto common

is_non_virtual:
  %memptr.non_virtual = %memptr.ptr

common:
   if we came from 
      is_non_virtual: %8 = %memptr.non_virtual
      is_virtual: %8 = %memptr.virutal
   call %8
```

I skipped some type-casts and stuff to make it simpler.

**NOTE** This is NOT meant to say "this is how it is implemented always. It's one example of what the compiler MAY do. Different compilers will do this subtly differently. But if the function may or may not be virtual, the compiler first has to figure out which. [In the above example, I'm fairly sure we can turn on optimisation and get much better code, but it would presumably just figure out exactly what's going on and remove all of the code, which for understanding how it works is pointless]

Comment: what is the assembly like output that you have in you answer called? How to generate it? And how did you make sense of it, in the `in essence` section, any book, links, would be great.

Comment: It is not a formal language, it's what is generally called "pseudo-code", in this case based on kind of LLVM-IR syntax, but I just made it up as I went along, so there is no book or similar, I just translated LLVM-IR into more human understandable form to describe the steps - simplified and less detailed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple answer to this. Pointers-to-methods are **not** 'normal' pointers and can not be cast to those, even through `reinterpret_cast`. One can cast first to `void*`, and than to the `long long`, but this is really ill-advised.

Remember, size of pointer-to-method is not neccessarily (and usually **is not**!) equal to the size of 'normal' pointer. The way most compilers implement pointer-to-method, it is twice the size of 'normal' pointer.

GCC is going to complain for the pointer-to-method to `void*` cast in pedantic mode, but will generate code still.

Comment: thanks, it worked. I just wanted to see the internals of method pointer, I am not using it in production code.

Comment: @q126y, most likely, you are not going to see *internals* of the pointer (whatever you mean by this). `void*` conversion is liklely to loose important pieces of it.

Comment: @SergeyA @tenfour
why will it lose important pieces? The bits will remain same, right? It will only be interpreted as `void*`, isn't it?

Comment: @q126y, no, and this is something what people are trying to explain to you all along. pointer to method is **not** a simple pointer, like a pointer-to-function.

Comment: @SergeyA yes, I understand that, but pointer to method has some size and some bit pattern. Yes, the bit patterns don't represent address of function, but it should be possible to inspect the bits associated with method pointer.

Comment: @q126y, for starters, size of pointer-to-method is not neccessary equal to the size of 'normal' pointer. On my system, it is 16 vs 8.

Comment: @SergeyA yes, I know that.